# Pivot Nested Columns (Grouped by Columns) - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to figure out if I can pivot these results as desired or if I need to code this report in Crystal or something.

DATA TO CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    #TempData (
                EMP NVARCHAR(35),
                WKDAY NVARCHAR(3),
                ENTRY_DATE DATETIME,
                REG_HOURS INT,
                OT_HOURS INT,
                PTO_HOURS INT);

INSERT INTO #TempData (EMP, WKDAY, ENTRY_DATE, REG_HOURS, OT_HOURS, PTO_HOURS)
VALUES ('Doe, John','Fri','2018-03-16 00:00:00.000','10','2','35'),
('Boop, Betty','Fri','2018-03-16 00:00:00.000','8','3','48'),
('Boop, Betty','Mon','2018-03-19 00:00:00.000','8','8','63'),
('Square, Sponge','Mon','2018-03-19 00:00:00.000','9','7','21'),
('Rabbit, Roger','Tue','2018-03-20 00:00:00.000','5','9','45'),
('Square, Sponge','Tue','2018-03-20 00:00:00.000','9','0','9'),
('Boop, Betty','Wed','2018-03-21 00:00:00.000','0','4','18'),
('Doe, John','Wed','2018-03-21 00:00:00.000','12','4','57'),
('Matrix, Neo','Thu','2018-03-22 00:00:00.000','8','6','24');
```

The results desired would be as seen in the below Pivot Nested Columns (Grouped by Columns):

```
WKDAY   DATE                                        Doe, John                               Boop, Betty                             Square, Sponge                                  Rabbit, Roger
                                        REG_HOURS   OT_HOURS    PTO_HOURS       REG_HOURS   OT_HOURS    PTO_HOURS           REG_HOURS   OT_HOURS    PTO_HOURS           REG_HOURS   OT_HOURS    PTO_HOURS
Fri     2018-03-16 00:00:00.000             10      2           35                      8           3           48                  0           0           0                   0           0           0
Mon     2018-03-19 00:00:00.000             0       0           0                       8           8           63                  9           7           21                  0           0           0   
Tue     2018-03-20 00:00:00.000             0       0           0                       0           0           0                   9           0           9                   5           9           45
```

It should be in this exact format, I don't want to consolidate column names via date or any other combination.

Is this possible?

The only alternative I see is coding it in a report like Crystal Reports or something like that.

Comment: You have right see, this should go with presentation layer.

Comment: This definitely should be handled in your presentation logic in my opinion.  Write the query to return the pivoted aggregated data per user per day, then format accordingly in Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot in the presentation layer. Crystal Reports, Excel, Access, Tableau, whatever.

Comment: Many Thanks. ... I didn't think it was possible, but two minds are better than 1.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, there is no concept of Column Groups.

You could get a result like this:

```
WKDAY   DATE                                        Doe_John_REG_HOURS     Doe_John_OT_HOURS      Doe_John_PTO_HOURS    Boop_Betty_REG_HOURS     Boop_Betty_OT_HOURS      Boop_Betty_PTO_HOURS        etc...
```

But the only way to have the exact format in your question, with two rows of column headers, is in a presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks for your added feedback. Presentation layer is the only way.